# translate from sql statement to lambda expression statement

Tags: c#-4.0

```
select * from employee where id in(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var employees = yourEmployeeStore.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.id));
```